# How to properly install Typescript, if to use in visual studio 2015 & angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm

I have made an angular 2 app with visual studio 2015, typescript. I installed typescript before creating project using npm cmd "npm install -g typescript@2.0" globally. Now when I am building the project it shows me several errors related to typescript. I Followed control panel -> programs -> typescript tools for visual studio 1.7.6. My question is, I installed typescript 2.0by npm globally then why it shows me above 1.7.6 version of typescript for vs15 ? Does installing typescript from microsoft website has anything to do with installing it by npm ? 
Any Understanding would be helpful!
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different beasts:

1. TypeScript extension for VisualStudio 2015 (2.2.1)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Once you install the extension, you should verify the version: Help > About > Scroll Down

2. Typescript package from npm (2.2.1)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript

It would be a good idea to make sure the versions are in sync.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! I am out of town, so i wont be able to see the effect after change. I will get back to you as soon as it works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Typescript & Node Latest Version from Microsoft web site. While installing close all the application after completing installation open the application. Now You will not found any error. The application will run successfully

```
Refer the link:

Node Latest Version: https://nodejs.org/en/
Typescript Latest Version : http://www.typescriptlang.org/
```